# I want my MovieClip to play from frame 5 to frame 30 and then stop. How?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, frame

I want my MovieClip to play from frame 5 to frame 30 and then stop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function playSegment(target:MovieClip, begin:int, end:int):void
{
    target.gotoAndPlay(begin);
    target.addEventListener(
        Event.ENTER_FRAME,
        function(e:Event):void
        {
            if(target.currentFrame == end)
            {
                target.stop();
                target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then do:

```
playSegment(your_movieclip, 5, 30);
```

Or if you have a base class/class set up for your MovieClip then you can of course do:

```
public function playSegment(begin:int, end:int):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(begin);
    addEventListener(
        Event.ENTER_FRAME,
        function(e:Event):void
        {
            if(currentFrame == end)
            {
                stop();
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then:

```
my_movieclip.playSegment(5, 30);
```

Comment: instead of using arguments.callee wouldn't it be more clear to use e.target?

Comment: **e.target** would be the **MovieClip**.. **removeEventListener()** accepts a function as its second argument? arguments.callee refers to the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with code, try this:

```
myMovieClip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
myMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(5);

private function onEnter(e:Event) : void {
    if(myMovieClip.currentFrame == 30) {
        myMovieClip.stop();
        myMovieClip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, actually that's how i implemented it myself, some seconds after posting a question. thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Nika Gamkrelidze That solution does indeed work well. I think you should consider Marty Wallaces first solution for anything less explicit than play from frame 5 to frame 30. Since that solution is more robust for the general case. I would however move the `onEnterFrame` function out of `playSegment`, and place it in it's own function, since that makes the code much easier to read and comprehend. That's just my personal preference though, his code works just fine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use addFrameScript method too.

```
protected function addMovieClip():void{
    mc = new MovieClip();
    addChild(mc);
    mc.gotoAndPlay(5);
    mc.addFrameScript(30, frameFunction);
}

protected function frameFunction():void
{
    mc.stop();
    //clear the code by writing null script to target frame.
    mc.addFrameScript(30, null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

on frame 1 add the actionscript type: `gotoAndPlay(5);` on frame 30 add `stop();`

Comment: oh sure, i forgot that... i was using document class so forgot about actions... can i use them both, interchangeably?...

Answer (score 1):

first frame: gotAndPlay(5) and in frame 30 a simple stop()?

Edit: This is actually more than basic Flash coding. So you perhaps do not know how to add script to a frame? See the Flash docs for "Adding interaction".